# How to use laravel route in ajax url

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This route marks notifications as read, using ajax

```
Route::get('markAsRead', function() {
    Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
    return Redirect()->back();
});

function markNotificationAsRead()
{
    $.get('markAsRead');
}
```

This works from the root directory:

```
http://localhost/markAsRead
```

but when i want to access this route from

```
http://localhost/user/markAsRead
```

it does not work, so how Can I use the laravel route and make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Without beginning slashes, the URL is relative to the current page. To make it absolute, you want to add a slash before it:

```
function markNotificationAsRead()
{
    $.get('/markAsRead');
}
```

Comment: @ThomasMoors that tag is irrelevant if answer is updating same code OP is using